# No backend database, only dynamically created table bound to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am need a solution like this: no backend database, no Xml, no Excel, only when user gives information display in GridData. Only creating dynamically in the `.aspx.cs` table and column ...

Eg:--

```
Name |-Text box-| Button
```

Gridview

When user visited page ..like above Name with TextBox and Submit Button  .

When user enters a name in the TextBox and clicks on submit I want to add that name to the grid, but here I want not only presented data... also previous enter data display in Gridview.

eg2:-

```
sairam  submit--->click
pamidi  submit-->click
```

I want display how many values user enter that many i want to display in gridview ,like this

```
sairam
pamidi
some....
more...
values..
```

up-to when user perform close of browser .

`info.aspx`:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Name"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox  ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSumbit"  runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSumbit_Click" />
      <asp:GridView ID="aspGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  >

       <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("Name") %>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

`info.aspx.cs`:

```
public partial class Default6 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        ViewState["DataTable"] = dt;

    }
    protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == " ")
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            aspGrid1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["DataTable"];
            aspGrid1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what the problem with this code

Comment: why don't you use sessions to store data.

Comment: You could put a variable (eg: LIST<T>) in Session or ViewState, and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the data somehow.

The Standard options include a database, a variable stored in session state or in-page hidden fields.  The .net control isn't going to databind to it's own `viewstate`.

A non-standard option would be to handle everything client side without post backs.  If you go this route you will be better served but not using the standard .net controls but rather use straight html.  This will require a fair bit of coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;


public partial class Default6 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable _dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            _dt = new DataTable();
            _dt = CreateDataTable();
            Session["DataTable"] = _dt;
            aspGrid1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["DataTable"]).DefaultView;
            aspGrid1.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == " ")
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        {

            AddDataTable(TextBox1.Text, (DataTable)Session["DataTable"]);
            aspGrid1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["DataTable"]).DefaultView;
            aspGrid1.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable datatable=new DataTable();

        DataColumn datacolumn=new DataColumn();
        datacolumn.ColumnName = "Name";
        datacolumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        datatable.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
        return datatable;
    }
    private void AddDataTable(string name,DataTable datatable)
    {

        DataRow dataRow;
        dataRow = datatable.NewRow();
        dataRow["Name"] = name;
        datatable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're creating the data table everytime you enter Page_Load.**

You need to check if you're not already have a data table in the ViewState and if you do - pull it out and add a new row, or create the data table for the first time.

The best way is to initialize the data table for the first time in the `if(!PostBack){...}` in Page_Load and store it in the Session (similary like ViewState, but reduces PostBack data from/to the client).

Then, if it's a postback, just get the data table from the session and add the new row to it.